# Reflection returns two constructors when accessing it's private constructor from an inner class

Tags: java, reflection

```
public class Base {

    private Base instance;

    private Base() {
    }

    public static class BaseHelper {
        Base instance = new Base();
    }
}
```

In above example I have one no-argument constructor in base class. Now I'm listing the constructors of this class like this:

```
Constructor<?>[] constructors = Base.class.getDeclaredConstructors();
System.out.println(constructors);
```

When running this code I get the following output:

```
[private com.Base(), com.Base(com.Base)]
```

This tells me that there are two constructors:

- a private constructor that I have declared
- a public default constructor

Why is this?

Comment: can you explain what do you mean by " but when I use reflection API I can see two constructor"? which two constructor?

Comment: Once the formatting is fixed, that is a good question. We should think about a better title though, so people with similar questions can find it more easily...

Comment: I agree. Why does this question have 4 downvotes? This is one of the best questions I've seen for ages. I don't believe the downvoters knew the answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The compiler creates two constructors, because your `BaseHelper` class accesses the private constructor of your `Base` class.

When compiled, the inner class is "extracted" from the containing class. If the class `BaseHelper` was outside the `Base` class it could not access the private constructor - that's why the compiler creates a synthetic constructor. This is the second constructor that you see.

[Synthetic is a field modifier](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/fieldModifiers.html) and in essence means compiler-generated.

```
package de.test;

import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;

public class Base {

    private Base instance;

    private Base() {
    }

    public static class BaseHelper {
        Base instance = new Base();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Constructor[] constructors = Base.class.getDeclaredConstructors();
        for (Constructor constructor : constructors) {
            System.out.println(constructor + " - synthetic? " + constructor.isSynthetic());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Max for your answer, I have one more doubt why Its creating constructor with parameter(as I mention in my question).

Comment: I could not find any reliable source on this, but I'd guess that the constructor requires an object of type `Base` to avoid that other code can not call this constructor via reflection.

Comment: It's not Base, it's Base$1. It looks like a synthetic class is created too.

Comment: @pbabcdefp where did you see that it's `Base$1`? For me outputting the class name of the constructors parameter gives a `de.test.Base`.

Comment: When I run your code above I get two lines of output: `private Base() - synthetic? false` and `Base(Base$1) - synthetic? true`.

Comment: When I run that code, I get these two lines: `private Base() - synthetic? false` and `Base(Base) - synthetic? true` (javac 1.7.0_17) :P

Comment: That is really weird. I think I'll post this as a question. I'm using java 8.

Comment: I also getting the same outPut as maxDev is getting.                                                                                private Base() - synthetic? false and Base(Base) - synthetic? true(java 1.6.0_27)

Comment: They've obviously decided to change it for java 8. I think maxdev's explanation of requiring a Base (to stop you calling this constructor via reflection) is very plausible. However the loophole is that Base could have another public constructor taking a String, say. In that case the synthetic constructor would still be needed if BaseHelper calls the private no-args constructor, and you could invoke the synthetic constructor by passing a Base constructed using a String. Creating a synthetic class tightens the whole thing up a bit.